# Is building a long range wifi antenna to connect to the up and coming starlink internet possible?

Tags: signal, antenna, networking, satellite

I want to try to convert a residential satellite dish into a long range wifi antenna to theoretically see if I can connect to the up & coming starlink internet that is being released in Canada and United States from virtually wherever.
It's just an experiment, and I don't intend to use it for illegal purposes. I imagine there must be some sort of security feature that would stop me from intercepting starlink wifi signals. But this is my first time ever doing anything of this nature, does anyone have any experience with intercepting or capturing wi-fi signals or could maybe tell me why my line of thinking is incorrect, or maybe if I'm possibly going in a right direction?

Comment: From what I understand about Starlink is that it’s private access. I don’t see how you plan on bypassing its security. I highly doubt Space X will allow you get into their systems because your own curiosity.

Comment: Whatever protocol they use, it won't be wi-fi. You'd have more luck with an SDR dongle like RTL-SDR and start with spectrum analysis software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea has technical, legal and possibly other important aspects.

First, Starlink is not WiFi.

I am yet to see their technical specs, but given the completely different task, spatial arrangement and business model, they use different frequency bands, probably different modulation schemes and probably different access protocol as well. Your high-gain antenna will have rather narrow beam width, so it will have to track some particular satellite as it orbits across the sky. They are on low orbit so each one of them is visible for less than an hour and then you have to communicate to another one. As I am thinking about the whole task, antenna is the easiest.

Legal: Frequency bands are a finite resource, so they are regulated by governments and international organizations (see ITU). In most jurisdictions, you are free to listen whatever you want (some restrictions may still apply, depending on where you live you may or may not be allowed to listen to police channels). In order to transmit, in most frequency bands you need an explicit permission and a transmitting device certified according to some standard. That's how mobile networks work - an operator pays a great deal of money to the government in order to use some frequency band and both the operator and the subscribers have to use compliant devices. Starlink will not be any different.

Business: the Starlink network will be open only for subscribers. Even if you get a subscription, you will be obligated (probably) to use equipment that only the operator sells or rents. They will rather not allow subscribers to use third-party devices, until some common standard for these types of communication is developed.

In short, find a better target for your curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Starlink doesn't use WiFi, so you won't be able to capture WiFi from it. If you had the right antenna and electronics (which you certainly do not given the cost), you could see the RF signal. You wouldn't be able to decode it however.

If you want to do amateur radio, there are lots of lower frequencies being used on ground and in orbit. These are much more accessible with affordable electronics.

Comment: Very cool, amateur radio does sound like a better direction! Maybe i'll try getting a book on that

Comment: Amateur radio is just a *type of usage*, not a concrete system.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the downlink signals if you like, but they won't be of any use to you since they will either be for other subscribers or encrypted or both. Even ordinary Wifi is encrypted, so it is likely that Starlink will be.

Details on how it works are sparse, but I imagine they won't accept transmissions from you without a paying subscription, and a one-way internet is of very little use.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it is *possible* to build an antenna for it, as they must have built antennas if they are selling them.

However, what makes you think the satellite system even uses WiFi signaling?

Most likely it does not, so by combining a WiFi base station with a satellite dish, it will not be possible to communicate with the system in any level.

So without specification how it works and proper tools to make it work, you won't be able to build one.

And by looking at Wikipedia, it seems to use frequency bands above 10GHz, so no, it won't be compatible with your WiFi equipment. It also does not use a single dish but a phased array antenna.

Comment: Thank-you, I definitely had a base misunderstanding of the technology.